# make header of resizable column ( using inside div and resize) fit it's content and table content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this table with resizable columns. the div inside the  header  allows me to push the neighboring column out of the frame when resizing. My issue is that now when I resize the column down, it is doing this:

[image]

I managed to make the sizing stop at the size of the table content by using  min-width 100% on the div.

[image]

But if the header name is bigger than the content, it still cut the header name. So now I also would like the div to stop shrinking at it's own content size. so I would need two min-width criteria. how can I do that ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

th {
  border: 1px solid;
  min-width: fit-content;
}

.mainContainer{
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000000;
}

.thDiv {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  border-width: 1px;
  min-width: 100%;
}

td {
    border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class = "mainContainer">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ><div class = "thDiv">TESTTESTESTTT</div></th>
                <th ><div class = "thDiv">TESTTESTESTEST</div></th>
                <th ><div class = "thDiv">TEST</div></th>
                <th ><div class = "thDiv">TEST</div></th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>TESTTES</td>
              <td>TESTTES</td>
              <td>TESTTES</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>TESTTTTT</td>
                <td>TESTTESTESTESTESTSTETSET</td>
                <td>TESTTESTES</td>
                <td>TESTTESTES</td>
                
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>TESTT</td>
                <td>TESTTESTESTESTESTSTETSET</td>
                <td>TESTTESTE</td>
                <td>TESTTESTE</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the `min-width` of the `thDiv` class to `min-content`. MDN defines [the `min-content` sizing keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-content) as "representing the intrinsic minimum width of the content. For text content this means that the content will take all soft-wrapping opportunities, becoming as small as the longest word".

In addition, I added a red border on the `thDiv` class so that you can see more easily how it changes size.

If you don't want the headings to wrap, then you should avoid soft spaces in the heading. To do this, I added hard spaces, `&nbsp;`, in the first heading.

The `th` element itself does not need a `min-width: fit-content` attribute.

It is now possible to drag the heading left and right and the whole heading will always be visible without any overlapping or vertical resizing of the headings.

```css
th {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.mainContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000000;
}

.thDiv {
  border: solid 3px red;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: min-content;
}

td {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="thDiv">TEST&nbsp;TEST&nbsp;ESTTT</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="thDiv">TESTTESTESTEST</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="thDiv">TEST</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="thDiv">TEST</div>
        </th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>TESTTES</td>
        <td>TESTTES</td>
        <td>TESTTES</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TESTTTTT</td>
        <td>TESTTESTESTESTESTSTETSET</td>
        <td>TESTTESTES</td>
        <td>TESTTESTES</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TESTT</td>
        <td>TESTTESTESTESTESTSTETSET</td>
        <td>TESTTESTE</td>
        <td>TESTTESTE</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```